# OS: wait() in child process

Tags: c, operating-system, wait, child-process

Learning OS, it has been usually seen in any textbooks that using fork() in the parent process to create a child process, and sometimes call wait() in the parent to wait for the completion of the child.

But, what happens, if I use wait() in the child?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int
main(int argc, char** argv){
  int x;
  int w1, w2;
  x = 100;
  printf("the initialized x is: %d\n",x);
  int rc = fork();
  if(rc < 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "fork failed.\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  else if(rc == 0){
    //x = 200;                                                                  
    w1 = wait(NULL);
    printf("the x in child process (pid:%d) is: %d\n", (int) getpid(), x);
  } else {
    x = 300;
    w2 = wait(NULL);
    printf("the x in parent process (pid:%d) is: %d\n",(int) getpid(), x);
  }
  printf("the x in the end is: %d\n",x);
  printf("the returns of waits: %d, %d\n",w1,w2);
  return 0;
}
```

This piece of code runs and shows the following:

```
dhcp175:hw_ch5 Suimaru$ ./a.out 
the initialized x is: 100
the x in child process (pid:18844) is: 100
the x in the end is: 100
the returns of waits: -1, 0
the x in parent process (pid:18843) is: 300
the x in the end is: 300
the returns of waits: 0, 18844
```

How to explain it?

Answer (score 5):

> But, what happens, if I use wait() in the child?

Have you read its documentation?  Especially the parts about return value and error conditions?  I see that you have performed an experiment, which is good; between that and the docs, it should already be clear that if the process that calls `wait()` has no child processes to wait for, then it immediately returns `-1`, indicating an error.  In that event, `errno` will be set to `ECHILD`.

And returning immediately with an error makes perfect sense, for the only other alternative if the calling process has no children is for it to wait, possibly indefinitely, for an event that cannot occur as long as it is waiting.

Answer (score 2):

You have already said what happens in your sample output, but to get more detail you have to check the `errno` value after receiving a failure code from the `wait` system call.  While checking `if (errno == ECHILD)` is helpful and can be used to perform some action that may handle this error, you can also get a string (character array) with an error message using the following code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

...

char err_msg[4096]; // a buffer big enough to hold an error message
errno = 0; // clear errno just in case there was an earlier error
pid_t fpid = fork();
if (fpid < 0)
{
    perror("fork failed.\n"); // prints out an error string based on errno
    exit(1);
} else if (fpid == 0)
{ // in child
    pid_t wpid = wait(NULL);                                                             
    strerror_r(errno, err_msg, sizeof(err_msg)); // gets an error string
    printf("child process (pid:%d), wpid:%d, %s\n", (int) getpid(), (int)wpid, err_msg);
} else {
    int err_val;
    wpid = wait(NULL);
    err_val = errno;
    errno = 0; // reset errno
    strerror_r(err_val , err_msg, sizeof(err_msg)); // gets an error string
    printf("parent process (pid:%d), wpid:%d, %s\n", (int) getpid(), (int)wpid, err_msg);
    if (err_val != 0)
    {
        // there was an error, so what are you going to do about it?
    }
}
```